# TabView with WebView

Tags: android, webview, tabview

I have 3 tab in a page and each tab one activity is calling but when we called an activity Web view my tab is vanish and full page taken by web view only please tell me how to display Tab view with Web View is my 3rd Tab. and when i come back to tab view using back key it is showing black screen only..

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TabHost tabHost=getTabHost();
    // no need to call TabHost.Setup()       
    //First Tab
    TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
    spec1.setIndicator("Registration",getResources().
    getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    Intent in1=new Intent(this,RegistrationActivity.class);
    spec1.setContent(in1);

    TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    spec2.setIndicator("Login",getResources().
    getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    Intent in2=new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
    spec2.setContent(in2);

    TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    spec3.setIndicator("WebView",getResources().
    getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    Intent in3=new Intent(this,WebViewActivity.class);
    spec3.setContent(in3);

    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
    tabHost.addTab(spec3);
}
```

web view Activity

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.webview);

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
webView.getParent();
```

main tab xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="90"> 

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" />

        </ScrollView> 

        <TabWidget
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Webview xml

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: @RanjanSharan Please post some code or post more information so we can help you more.

Comment: hi, dude this is my code plz guide me..